# execute spring job with scheduler except holidays

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-batch

I have a java job configured with @EnableScheduling and I am able to run job with annotation

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${job1.outgoingCron:0 45 15,18,20 * * MON-FRI}", zone = "America/New_York")
public void Process() {

}
```

But I don't want to run this job for US holidays what is the best way to update schedule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set your schedule [explicitly](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#scheduling-trigger-implementations), using `CronTrigger` or custom `Trigger`, for example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
        return new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    }
}

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor // Lombok annotation
public class StartUp implements ApplicationRunner {

    @NonNull private final TaskScheduler scheduler;

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {

        // Variant 1 
        scheduler.schedule(this::myTask, new CronTrigger(/* your schedule */));

        // Variant 2
        scheduler.schedule(this::myTask, this::myTriger);
    }

    private void myTask() {
        //...
    }

    private Date myTrigger(TriggerContext triggerContext) {
       //...
    }
}
```